# NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION not throwing warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-warnings, llvm-clang

I was referring to this link (*used google translate to read*) - [about NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION](http://dev.classmethod.jp/references/ios8-ns_designated_initializer-ns_protocol_requires_explicit_implementation/)

I'm trying to get `NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION` to throw warning in my project when a required method in a protocol needs to be implemented by all subclassess too.

**Here's the protocol -**

```
NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION
@protocol ExplicitProtocol <NSObject>

@required
- (void)requiredMethod1;
- (void)requiredMethod2;

@optional
- (void)optionalMethod1;
- (void)optionalMethod2;

@end
```

**Base class header -**

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject<ExplicitProtocol>

@end
```

**Base class implementation -**

```
@implementation BaseClass

-(void)requiredMethod1
{

}

-(void)requiredMethod2
{

}

@end
```

**SubClass header**

```
@interface SubClass : BaseClass

@end
```

**SubClass implementation**

```
@implementation SubClass
//No protocol methods implemented here
@end
```

Since the requiredMethods are not implemented in `SubClass` I want a warning to be thrown.

Is there a way to achieve this in Objective C? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you certain that `NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION` is defined when you're compiling?

Comment: Or rather, is defined to have a useful value?

Comment: isn't it defined in the NSObjCRuntime.h. Do i have to redefine it?
Still, i added #ifndef `NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION
#if __has_attribute(objc_protocol_requires_explicit_implementation)
#define NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION __attribute__((objc_protocol_requires_explicit_implementation))
#else
#define NS_PROTOCOL_REQUIRES_EXPLICIT_IMPLEMENTATION
#endif
#endif` on top of the protocol header and ran the app. It doesnt throw warnings.